# CSS3 flex li 2 columns change order

Tags: css, flexbox

I need a list which will sort my items like this

```
- 1  - 4
- 2  - 5
- 3
```

And I need to have dymamic height of this content

It works for me when I use this code for ul

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
max-height: 200px;
```

But I need to have max-height autmatic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved without flex styles. It is possible with coulmn count and gap.
Ul style code should look like this

```
ul {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
}

li {
  widh: 100%; // of column 
}
```

works fine for me.